# Cannot create hourly trigger near minute 16 in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers

I ran the following function in Google Apps Script:

```
function createTrigger() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('myFunction')
    .timeBased()
    .nearMinute(16)
    .everyHours(1)
    .create();
}
```

and a trigger was created which runs every hour at minute 52. According to [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder#nearminuteminute), `.nearMinute(16)` should create a trigger that runs between minute 1 and minute 31. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Has it been created and run at minute 52?

Comment: @ziganotschka Yes, the script created it at minute 52 (even though it should be at minute 1-31) and it has been running every hour.

Answer (score 0):

### [nearMinute(minute)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder#nearminuteminute)  does not refer to the minute at which the trigger is created, but the one close to which it will run every hour

- As for the creation time, in your case the trigger gets created directly when you run the function `createTrigger()`.
- However, for a [clock trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder#nearMinute(Integer)) the creation time is not important and does not affect at what time the trigger will run.
- Your function builds a trigger that will run each hour near minute 16 - no matter at what time the trigger is created.

Comment: Yes, I understand this. The trigger runs evey hour at minute 52, even though it should run between minute 1 and minute 31. Sorry if my question was unclear. I will try to improve the wording.

Comment: This is really strange. Do you have this problem only if you create the trigger programmatically or also manually? I just set-up a test function like yours and the created trigger ran for me pretty close to the minute value I specified. Maybe try to delete all your old /redundant triggers and then set-up a new one?

Comment: The problem is only with triggers created programmatically. I have already tried deleting and recreating the trigger, several times. It is indeed weird! Maybe you got lucky? If you programmatically create a bunch of triggers with my code, do they all run between minute 1-31?

Comment: Keep in mind that you can create max. 20 triggers per script: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas. I wouldn't say one is "lucky" if a trigger fires on time - this is my usual experience with triggers and the one I created this morning keeps firing correctly close to the specified minute. Maybe try to create a new script project with a minimal code and set-up a single trigger?

Comment: When  creating a bunch of triggers I noticed that the more triggers I create - the more delay there is between them being fired - it indicates that there might be some exponential backoff logarithm involved at the backend. However the 5 triggers I just created all fired within the +15 minutes window. Mind however [The time may be slightly randomized — for example, if you create a recurring 9 a.m. trigger, Apps Script chooses a time between 9 a.m. and 10 a.m](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers).

Comment: I assume if you stretch it with creating bunches of triggers, this is where the backend implementation will make the delays in execution increase.